# Begin and End Invoke in a single extension method properly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, extension-methods, func

I want to double check with others whether this would be the correct way to create an extension method that begins an asynchronous process, and returns a function that when invoked essentially waits on that process and gets the result.

```
    public static Func<R> HandleInvoke<T, R>(this Func<T, R> function, T arg, Action<IAsyncResult> callback)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = function.BeginInvoke(arg, new AsyncCallback(callback), function);

        return delegate
        {
            return function.EndInvoke(result);
        };
    }
```

Essentially I want to use it like such (pseudo code):

```
Func<R> myFunc = (some delegate).HandleInvoke(arg, callback);  
                     // at this point the operation begins, but will be nonblocking

                     // do other stuff

var result = myFunc();   // now I am deciding to wait on the result, which is blocking
```

Wasnt sure if I need to worry about waiting on WaitHandles in this situation or not. Also not sure if passing in a callback would even be necessary. Also I think this constitutes a closure?

**EDIT**

Ended up with this,

```
    public static Func<R> HandleInvoke<T, R>(this Func<T, R> function, T arg)
    {
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = function.BeginInvoke(arg, iAsyncResult =>
            {
                if (!(iAsyncResult as AsyncResult).EndInvokeCalled)
                {
                    (iAsyncResult.AsyncState as Func<T, R>).EndInvoke(iAsyncResult);
                }

            }, function); 

        return delegate
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle }); 

            return function.EndInvoke(asyncResult); 
        };
    }
```

Which seems to work well. The callback checks if EndInvoke has been called, and if not, calls it. Otherwise EndInvoke is called within the returned delegate.

2ND EDIT

Here is my latest attempt -- hasnt thrown any errors at me yet and seems to handle it well. I couldn't get it to work where the delegate returned the function.EndInvoke() result, but the delegate waits until EndInvoke has been called in the anonymous callback before returning R. Thread.Sleep() probably isnt the best solution, though. Also could use more checking to make sure that R was actually assigned to in each case.

```
    public static Func<R> HandleInvoke<T, R>(this Func<T, R> function, T arg)
    {
        R r = default(R); 

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = function.BeginInvoke(arg, result =>
            {
                r = (result.AsyncState as Func<T, R>).EndInvoke(result);

            }, function); 


        return delegate
        {
            while (!(asyncResult as AsyncResult).EndInvokeCalled)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1); 
            }

            return r; 
        };
    }
```

Comment: If you can use .NET 4 then the Task<TResult> class is worth a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx (probably better than rolling your own stuff)

Comment: Thanks. I will probably end up using something like that, no need to reinvent the wheel. Was just curious about the possibility of creating such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work but I'm not keen on the design...  Here is the basic problem.

If myFunc is called than you should not call EndInvoke in the callback but if myFunc is not called, because you don't care about the return value then EndInvoke must be called in the callback.  This makes using the API non-obvious and error prone.

with the sleep you have in there it is racy, though it isn't likely to bite you very often.  This uses proper synchronization primitives to guarantee that everything will happen in the right order.  This is untested code, but should work

```
    public static Func<R> HandleInvoke<T, R>(this Func<T, R> function, T arg)
    {
        R retv = default(R);
        bool completed = false;

        object sync = new object();

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = function.BeginInvoke(arg, 
            iAsyncResult =>
            {
                lock(sync)
                {
                    completed = true;
                    retv = function.EndInvoke(iAsyncResult);
                    Monitor.Pulse(sync); // wake a waiting thread is there is one
                }
            }
            , null);

        return delegate
        {

            lock (sync)
            {
                if (!completed) // if not called before the callback completed
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(sync); // wait for it to pulse the sync object
                }
                return retv;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I see...because I am not gauranteeing that EndInvoke is always called, is that you mean?

Comment: exactly.  your update is better, but you might as well capture `function` as well.

Comment: Added another edit, but I realized that it doesnt exactly work perfectly either. Is there any way to get the result of the method besides calling EndInvoke()? Because depending on the operation EndInvoke() could be called twice, and that throws a runtime error.

Comment: its actually kind of tricky to make this work with the callback optional in a way that doesn't leak and doesn't race.  I can post code in the answer that does it if you want... if you would rather work it out on your own take a look at `System.Monitor`

Comment: I made another attempt (2nd edit) and it hasnt thrown any errors, but it could be leaky I guess. If you have a better solution thatd be cool.

Comment: @Sean Thoman there you go... I may end up using that actually

Answer (score 1):

I came across a simpler way of doing it, where you get the benefit of having exceptions (re)throw at the invocation site, instead of on the background thread:

```
    public static Func<R> Future<T, R>(this Func<T, R> func, T arg)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = func.BeginInvoke(arg, null, null);

        return () => func.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

It's nearly identical for an Action:

```
    public static Action Future<T>(this Action<T> action, T arg)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = action.BeginInvoke(arg, null, null);

        return () => action.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

But if you don't have any need for the result then ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() is more efficient.